# Valgrind pthreads strange errors

Tags: c, raspberry-pi, pthreads, valgrind

I am testing Valgring different tools and I get an strange error using helgrind. I am using an Raspberry Pi 3 and the program is in C language. I took this program from internet just to try that everything is okay but I got lots of error in valgrind.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define NUM_THREADS 3


void *print_hello(void *threadid)
{
    long tid;
    tid = (long)threadid;


    printf("Thread number \t %ld sleeps %ld seconds...\n",tid,tid);
    sleep(tid);
    printf("Thread number \t %ld exiting .............\n",tid);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
    long array_ids[NUM_THREADS];
    int rc=0;
    long t;

    for(t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++)
    {
        array_ids[t]=t;
        printf("In main: creating thread %ld\n", array_ids[t]);
        rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, print_hello, (void *)t);
        if (rc)
        {
            printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", rc);
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    for (t=0;t<NUM_THREADS;t++)
    {
        pthread_join(threads[t],NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Valgrind output

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Documents $ sudo valgrind --tool=helgrind ./TestJulenCrossToolchain 
==1024== Helgrind, a thread error detector
==1024== Copyright (C) 2007-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP et al.
==1024== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==1024== Command: ./TestJulenCrossToolchain
==1024== 
In main: creating thread 0
==1024== ---Thread-Announcement------------------------------------------
==1024== 
==1024== Thread #2 was created
==1024==    at 0x4977548: clone (clone.S:62)
==1024== 
==1024== ---Thread-Announcement------------------------------------------
==1024== 
==1024== Thread #1 is the program's root thread
==1024== 
==1024== ----------------------------------------------------------------
==1024== 
==1024== Possible data race during read of size 4 at 0x4030558 by thread #2
==1024== Locks held: none
==1024==    at 0x400A430: _dl_lookup_symbol_x (dl-lookup.c:720)
==1024==    by 0x400F3B7: _dl_fixup (dl-runtime.c:111)
==1024==    by 0x4015F4F: _dl_runtime_resolve (dl-trampoline.S:57)
==1024==    by 0x4865DF7: start_thread (pthread_create.c:246)
==1024==    by 0x4977597: ??? (clone.S:92)
==1024== 
==1024== This conflicts with a previous write of size 4 by thread #1
==1024== Locks held: none
==1024==    at 0x400A440: _dl_lookup_symbol_x (dl-lookup.c:720)
==1024==    by 0x400F3B7: _dl_fixup (dl-runtime.c:111)
==1024==    by 0x4015F4F: _dl_runtime_resolve (dl-trampoline.S:57)
==1024==    by 0x48373AB: pthread_create_WRK (hg_intercepts.c:267)
==1024==    by 0x10803: main (TestJulenCrossToolchain.c:104)


 Lots of lines....


> ==1024==    at 0x5E9A1A8: ??? (in /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1)
    > ==1024== 
    > ==1024== This conflicts with a previous write of size 4 by thread #2
    > ==1024== Locks held: 1, at address 0x4030514
    > ==1024==    at 0x400C760: _dl_relocate_object (dl-machine.h:414)
    > ==1024==    by 0x40146E3: dl_open_worker (dl-open.c:427)
    > ==1024==    by 0x400FE93: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:187)
    > ==1024==    by 0x4013D47: _dl_open (dl-open.c:661)
    > ==1024==    by 0x49AEDEB: do_dlopen (dl-libc.c:87)
    > ==1024==    by 0x400FE93: _dl_catch_error (dl-error.c:187)
    > ==1024==    by 0x49AEED3: dlerror_run (dl-libc.c:46)
    > ==1024==    by 0x49AEF53: __libc_dlopen_mode (dl-libc.c:163)
    > ==1024== 
    > ==1024== ----------------------------------------------------------------
    > ==1024== 
    > ==1024== Possible data race during read of size 4 at 0x5EAC4D0 by thread #3
    > ==1024== Locks held: none
    > ==1024==    at 0x5E8D044: ??? (in /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1)
    > ==1024== 
    > ==1024== This conflicts with a previous write of size 4 by thread #2
    > ==1024== Locks held: none
    > ==1024==    at 0x400F40C: _dl_fixup (dl-machine.h:265)
    > ==1024==    by 0x4015F4F: _dl_runtime_resolve (dl-trampoline.S:57)
    > ==1024==    by 0x5E9A1C7: ??? (in /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgcc_s.so.1)
    > ==1024==  Thread number    2 exiting .............
    > ==1024== 
    > ==1024== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
    > ==1024== Use --history-level=approx or =none to gain increased speed, at
    > ==1024== the cost of reduced accuracy of conflicting-access information
    > **==1024== ERROR SUMMARY: 238 errors from 32 contexts (suppressed: 185 from 45)**
```

I took the code from here: http://www.it.uc3m.es/pbasanta/asng/course_notes/helgrind_tool_en.html

Comment: Use of 'long' data type?

Comment: I have tried with int type and I get the same error. Using  --tool=drd I do not get any error.